# вызов метода из null (я в шоке, что что, но такое использование null я не ожидал)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, методы, null

Здравствуйте уважаемые коллеги. Я начинающий программист, решил изучить код одной java игры, недостающие библиотеки классов скачал, все что надо было включил в проект.. но заметил интересное - красные линии Intellij не перестал показывать. 
Гляну, а там собственно и сюрприз, вот ниже собственно и он.. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знал, что вообще может быть код вроде этого " null.anyStaticMethod()" 
Прочел недавно схожий вопрос...
вроде смутно понятно, но еще одна преграда на пути к пониманию - если static метод каким то образом все таки реально вызывать через null то почему тогда у меня этот самый метод красный?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Ты просто распаковал апк что ли и теперь хочешь скомпилить его?

Comment: Судя по логике кода у вас неправильно код декомпилировался. Вместо null должно быть `var16`